# SQL Server Import Data: How to set datetime offset as default date type in imports?

Tags: sql-server, datetime, ms-access, import, datetimeoffset

We are importing large amounts of data from legacy systems. The data is coming from MS Access, where several tables have **DateTime**-typed data.

Unfortunately, users have entered wrong year values, like year '216'.

By default, MS SQL Server uses **DateTime** as date datatype. This causes import errors, as the min value for **DateTime** is January 1, 1753. If the date datatype would be **DateTimeOffset**, the import would be successful.

Is there any way to set make SQL server to use **DateTimeOffset** as the default type for date typed data when importing data?

Comment: How you are importing this data?

Comment: Have you tried importing the values to a NVarchar filed and then update the same the desired field after exporting to the table ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [SQL Server Migration Assistant for Access (AccessToSQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssma/access/sql-server-migration-assistant-for-access-accesstosql)

Then adjust the mapping of the fields: 
[Edit Type Mapping (AccessToSQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssma/access/edit-type-mapping-accesstosql)

But why not correct these easily identifiable errors before the import?

Comment: This solved the problem. DateTime2 type was set as default when importing the data. Thanks.

Comment: Ah, that explains.